# devtools::document tries to open directory as file

Tags: r, devtools

I'm trying to use `devtools::document()` to build the man files for an R package. However, when I call `document()` from inside my package, I get the following:

```
Updating xpcaR documentation
Loading xpcaR
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... roxy_tag_rd.roxy_tag_example -> read_lines -> <Anonymous> -> file
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In file(con, "r") :
  'raw = FALSE' but '/Users/andersonberg1/Documents/GitLab/xpcar/xpcaR/' is not a regular file
2: In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '/Users/andersonberg1/Documents/GitLab/xpcar/xpcaR/': it is a directory
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

The warning is completely correct: `.../xpcaR/` is a directory, not a file. In fact, it's the directory I'm in when I call `document()`. Why is it trying to open a directory as a file?

My current thought is that for some reason it's looking for some filename, coming up empty and so when it does

```
full_filename = paste0(path2package, filename)
```

`filename` is NULL so it ends up with just a path to the package. However, I can't figure out why that would be.

Answer (score 3):

I realized the issue was that I was writing an `#' @example`, but had not yet filled out that field. In short

```
#' ...
#' @examples
#' @export
foo = function(){}
```

caused the error above, but

```
#' ...
#' @examples
#' print("Hello world")
#' @export
foo = function(){}
```

fixed it.